Need help adding a transparent background to a group of layer elements
I have a site I'm working on that's designed on a template. The homepage slider content that's in the center of the slide are divided into layers. This is how the template designed it. I need to give all of the content a transparent background. That way it can display better visually. I'm looking for a div that has all of the layers in it. That way I can add the transparency to that 1 div. So far all I'm seeing is how to add a transparent background to each layer individually. Can someone help me give a transparent background to all the content as one. Below is the closest element I came up with but it's still not working.
rs-layer:not(.rs-wtbindex), .rs-layer:not(.rs-wtbindex), rs-alyer *:not(.rs-wtbindex), .rs-layer *:not(.rs-wtbindex)

Site Link: https://charismahomedecor.com



Try .eltdf-slider {opacity: 0.0}.

.eltdf-banner-image img, rs-sbg { 
   opacity: <your value> 
}

result: 

Thank you both for your comments but both suggestions is making the entire image transparent. I only want the section that has content written on it transparent. Do you have any suggestions for that?

then it's only rs-sbg { ... } part
